# SWIFT Sample Store for Developers to Write Parser

Tags: swift-mt

I am looking for a sample bank of swift messages, Say for example 101 the swift provides a extensive [documentation](https://www2.swift.com/knowledgecentre/publications/us1m_20180720/2.0?topic=afa.htm%23mt101) on the website.

But there is no full sample. a complete swift message which could be used for testing and constructing a parser.

did try google but could not find samples for all the message types.

I had some free time so thought i could do some good by writing the parser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm one of the authors of the Prowide libraries for SWIFT. You can use our open source SWIFT MT parser instead of writing your own:

https://github.com/prowide/prowide-core

For the messages structure, our library model Javadoc might be useful.
Take a look at Javadocs for each MTnnn class where you will find the message structure in terms of the sequences and the mandatory and optional fields. 
Then in the Javadocs for each Fieldnnn you can see the internal structure for each field components.

https://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.prowidesoftware/pw-swift-core

As for samples for all message types, you might be able to find some googling, but there is no comprehensive sample store that I know.